# Can we have a link to suspension information in the mod message templates?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, account-suspension

I find that I often write a short blurb about suspension when I'm suspending a user, often the same blurb about how their rep will be set at 1 but current rep is restored after the suspension.  I started adding this because I had confused, irate users replying to my suspension messages.

It would be really helpful if we had a couple of standard sentences in the templates, and possibly a link to "A Day in the Penalty Box" or some other useful description of what the user should expect when they are suspended. I think this would make it less stressful for the user.

(I mostly use the low-quality contributions template, if that's relevant.)

Comment: Hey where's your avatar??

Comment: @Sha What do you mean? It's right there, a beautiful representation of the [IPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invisible_Pink_Unicorn).

Comment: Hmm.. interesting that Google thinks your avatar is actually [gold business card](http://www.google.co.uk/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivRpRIgGYfnxx0yg1U9EWLnWUrX3itqm3v62pEZuYjf9CdR1Abi1aRrwTEG_1vAvufXxZrJYYeUDk59P2kEs0Pf9isTAs6V0ayBp6OCYJCvBTZ06GBwIL-BXG2Bp8kmLq_1x-OS9jBidg95cEiO_1KLfrF8KP6qttjgtH3jV70bWGPqNrdh5dweMLjyFz0Z1mE3nnR2T1WS-kEzhTPHaPBF2zGbzKBNtN6tZ8SOzYBuityQTHCXL_1pBxjGQWeTUJiB1OFx36d4I2sMhPDjMnTSHDLj60HlqklHSnGIH6X30l-BBFjtuVd-hd3dgaRDjDeMiQT6c_1qM8L3NgWeItxj0Wu8TP0gg7w&hl=en&bih=941&biw=1400)!

Comment: Doesn't the user see a banner near the top of every page they browse during suspension? That banner contains a link to the same blog post.

Comment: @Bolt But that requires them to go to their profile and look, which they haven't had time to do yet because they are surely plotting my demise immediately after reading the message. And anyway, that requires extra effort, attention, and savvy when they are already upset because they've been suspended because they can't figure out how the site works.

Comment: Oh. Every page? I don't know. I haven't been suspended before.

Comment: Actually, I don't know either. It would *make sense* for a suspended user to see it on every page view, but whether a user does see it I am not sure either :S